# Converting 2D Matrix - Dataframe to Flat Table in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe that looks like this:

```
  id  header1 header2 header3 ... headerN
  a      997    154.5   0.8        .... 
  b      0.3      3.4   6.7        ....
  c      7        8      9        ....
  .
  .
  .
```

I want to convert this to a flat table that looks something like this:

```
a header1 997
a header2 154.5
a header3 0.8
b header1 0.3
b header2 0.3
```

etc.

Each header column name is unique. The first column names are IDs. How can I most efficiently convert this in PySpark? I can loop through the DataFrame, but there must be a more efficient way.

Here is a sample dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('a',997.0,154.5,0.8),
    ('b',0.3,3.4,6.7),
    ('c',7.0,8.0,9.0)],
    ['id','header1','header2','header3'])
```

Comment: The question isn't very clear. Are you looking to change the formatting or reduce the table down to a set number of columns?

Comment: @AlphaTested I am looking to change the formatting of the table. The current table is a sort of 2D matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach -

*Step one*: `collect` columns except id into a `map` column using [create_map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.create_map) function;

*Step two*: [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode) the map column;

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import create_map, lit, explode, col

map_cols = (c for x in df.columns if x != 'id' for c in [lit(x), col(x)])
df.select('id', explode(create_map(*map_cols))).show()
+---+-------+-----+
| id|    key|value|
+---+-------+-----+
|  a|header1|997.0|
|  a|header2|154.5|
|  a|header3|  0.8|
|  b|header1|  0.3|
|  b|header2|  3.4|
|  b|header3|  6.7|
|  c|header1|  7.0|
|  c|header2|  8.0|
|  c|header3|  9.0|
+---+-------+-----+
```